# Finding all weekdays in a month

Tags: php, date, time

How do I go about getting all the **work** days (mon-fri) in a given time period (let's say, today till the end of the next month) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.2+ you can use the library I wrote in order to handle date recursion in PHP called [When](https://github.com/tplaner/When).

With the library, the code would be something like:

```
$r = new When();
$r->recur(<start date here>, 'weekly')
  ->until(<end date here>)
  ->wkst('SU')
  ->byday(array('MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR'));

while($result = $r->next())
{
    echo $result->format('c') . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Nice library though this is probably from the old version, is there any documentation for the new version? Some of those methods don't exist I think.

Answer (score 3):

This sample does exactly what you need, in an quick and efficient way.
It doesn't do nested loops and uses the totally awesome [DateTime](http://nl2.php.net/datetime) object.

```
$oDateTime = new DateTime();
$oDayIncrease = new DateInterval("P1D");

$aWeekDays = array();
$sStart = $oDateTime->format("m-Y");
while($oDateTime->format("m-Y") == $sStart) {
    $iDayInWeek = $oDateTime->format("w");
    if ($iDayInWeek > 0 && $iDayInWeek < 6) {
        $aWeekDays[] = clone $oDateTime;

    }
    $oDateTime->add($oDayIncrease);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it here: http://codepad.org/wuAyAqnF

To use it, simply pass a timestamp to `get_weekdays`.  You'll get back an array of all the weekdays, as timestamps, for the rest of the current month.  Optionally, you can pass a `$to` argument - you will get all weekdays between `$from` and `$to`.

```
function get_weekdays ($from, $to=false) {
    if ($to == false)
        $to = last_day_of_month($from);

    $days = array();

    for ($x = $from; $x < $to; $x+=86400 ) {
        if (date('w', $x) > 0 && date('w', $x) < 6)
            $days[] = $x;
    }
    return $days;       
}

function last_day_of_month($ts=false) {
    $m = date('m', $ts);
    $y = date('y', $ts);
    return mktime(23, 59, 59, ($m+1), 0, $y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could loop through the dates and check the **day** for each one, and increment a counter.

Can't think of anything else off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode coming your way:

Calculate the number of days between now and the last day of the month
Get the current day of the week (i.e. Wednesday)
Based on the current day of the week, and the number of days left in the month, it's simple calculation to figure out how many weekend days are left in the month - it's going to be the number of days remaining in the month, minus the number of Sundays/Saturdays left in the month.

I would write a function, something like:

```
daysLeftInMonth(daysLeftInMonth, startingDayOfWeek, dayOfWeekToCalculate)
```

where:

- daysLeftInMonth is last day of the month (30), minus the current date (15)
- startingDayOfWeek is the day of the week you want to start on (for today it would be Wednesday)
- dayOfWeekToCalculate is the day of the week you want to count, e.g. Saturday or Sunday. June 2011 currently has 2 Sunday, and 2 Saturdays left 'til the end of the month

So, your algorithm becomes something like:

```
getWeekdaysLeft(todaysDate)
```

...getWeekdaysLeft is something like:

```
sundaysLeft = daysLeftInMonth(lastDayOfMonth - todaysDate, "Wednesday", "Sunday");
saturdaysLeft = daysLeftInMonth(lastDayOfMonth - todaysDate, "Wednesday", "Saturday");
return ((lastDayOfMonth - todaysDate) - (sundaysLeft + saturdaysLeft));
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does at least one part you ask for. Instead of "end of next month" it simply works with a given number of days.

```
$dfrom = time();
$fourweeks = 7 * 4;

for ($i = 0; $i < $fourweeks; $i ++) {
    $stamp = $dfrom + ($i * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $weekday = date("D", $stamp);
    if (in_array($weekday, array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"))) {
        print date(DATE_RSS, $stamp) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find today's day of the month (i.e. 15)
$today = intval(date('d'));

// Define the array that will hold the work days.
$work_days = array()

// Find this month's last day. (i.e. 30)
$last = intval(date('d', strtotime('last day of this month')));

// Loop through all of the days between today and the last day of the month (i.e. 15 through 30)
for ( $i = $today; $i <= $last; $i++ )
{
  // Create a timestamp.
  $timestamp = mktime(null, null, null, null, $i);

  // If the day of the week is greater than Sunday (0) but less than Saturday (6), add the timestamp to an array.
  if ( intval(date('w', $timestamp)) > 0 && intval(date('w', $timestamp)) < 6 )
    $work_days[] = mktime($timestamp);
}
```

The `$work_days` array will contain timestamps which you could use this way:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $work_days[0]);
```

The code above with work in PHP 4 as well as PHP 5. It does not rely on the functionality of the DateTime class which was not available until PHP 5.2 and does not require the use of "libraries" created by other people.